# How to hide original text and ONLY show clone from that original text?

Tags: jquery, html

Good evening or good day.

I know this is a clone so it should be identical but, i was wondering if i can let the original title `display:none` and the clone of that original title display block? It doesn't seem to work? Is this even possible?

```
<div style='display:block;' class="clonedTitle1"></div> <!-- Is also hidden even when it is set to block -->

<h5 style='display:none;' class='testTitle1'>My Caption Title (1st Image)</h5>

<script>
  var $titleCarousel = $('.testTitle1').clone();
  $('.clonedTitle1').html($titleCarousel);
</script>
```

How can i `display:none` only the `.testTitle1`.

And only show the `.clonedTitle`.

I don't know if this a stupid question, sorry if what i am asking is not logical.

Thanks for your time and effort. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first clone the object when you can see it, and then set visibility to hidden

```js
var $titleCarousel = $('.testTitle1').clone();
  $('.clonedTitle1').html($titleCarousel);

  var h5 = document.getElementsByTagName('h5');
  h5[1].style.visibility='hidden';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style='display:block;' class="clonedTitle1"></div> <!-- Is also hidden even when it is set to block -->

<h5  class='testTitle1'>My Caption Title (1st Image)</h5>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your time and answer. The weird this is if we use `h5[0].style.visibility='hidden';` the `.clonedTitle1` gets hidden and the `.testTitle1` shows? Do you know why?

Comment: Are you still there? Hope that we can solve this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I updated my answer.  Since the clone appears first in the html it is h5[0], testTitle1 is h5[1]

Comment: @DRC Yes ofcouse, i was trying different things but didn't come up that the h5 = [1] . Thankyou very much for your time and solution.